# Update model that is connected via ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

Hi I have models that are contectet via foregin key. I can have multiple orders so let's say that i have 3 orders. 2xTshirt 1xPants and 4xHats. How can I acces each product and change the stock of them based on quantity of an order.
**views**

```py
order = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
for item in order_items:
    item.product.stock = int(item.product.stock) - int(item.quantity)
    item.transaction_id = transaction_id
    item.save()
```

**models**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    producent   = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    stock       = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the product object. Try this:

```
for item in order_items:
    product = item.product
    product.stock = product.stock - item.quantity
    product.save()
    item.transaction_id = transaction_id
    item.save()
```